# Do I need to install a desktop to run a nomachineNX server?

Tags: remote, x11, nx

I've installed a Ubuntu 12.04 cloud guest server.  I don't have a desktop.  I can open a X window remotely.  I'd like to improve the speed by installing nomachineNX server.

The community doc stays that I need to install a desktop.  Is that correct?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NomachineNX

I don't want to open a remote desktop, just individual X windows.  I don't see why I would need a desktop.

Btw, the doc is for 3.5.0.  Has anyone tried the 4.0 beta?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to install a desktop. In fact, for your use, I don't think you need to install X itself, since NX provides one itself.

Yes, someone has tried NX4. But that's a type of question that isn't suitable for this site.